# TclOO : Class Point

Tags: class, tcl

It's my first class, I am in the right direction ? I ask myself questions mainly on my **init**() method. Is alright ? I'm not sure… I'm looking for some advice, method…

```
oo::class create Point {

    variable x y z

    method init {val} {
        lassign $val x y z
    }

    method x {} {
        set x $x
    }

    method y {} {
        set y $y
    }

    method z {} {
        set z $z
    }

    method formatPoint {} {
        set x [format %.4f $x]
        set y [format %.4f $y]
        set z [format %.4f $z]
    }

}
proc distance3D {a b} {

    return [expr { \
            sqrt(([$a x] - [$b x])**2 \
               + ([$a y] - [$b y])**2 \
               + ([$a z] - [$b z])**2 )}]
}

set P0 [Point new]
set P1 [Point new]

$P0 init {8.2 30 40}
$P1 init {9.5 10 10}
set val [distance3D $P0 $P1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would probably be better to have a constructor rather than an init method:

```
constructor val {
    lassign $val x y z
}

set P0 [Point new {8.2 30 40}]
```

or

```
constructor args {
    lassign $args x y z
}

set P0 [Point new 8.2 30 40]
```

OOP-wise, a point without coordinates does not make much sense, and you probably don't want to "move" the point by changing the coordinates, so the coordinates should be assigned when creating the point, and the point replaced with a new one if the thing that owns the point moves.

Is it a good idea to change the coordinate values by the formatPoint method? Why not let the coordinates keep their values and provide a formatted access:

```
method formatPoint {} {
    format {%.4f %.4f %.4f} $x $y $z
}
```

The coordinate access methods are a little bit off. Try

```
method x {} {
    set x
}
```

instead: the unary form of set returns the value. Or

```
method x {} {
    return $x
}
```

if you prefer.

The calculation yields the correct result (~36.0789), but note that you don't need to escape line endings within the braces of an expression (since the line endings are already escaped by the braces).

Comment: The two ways of writing the `x` method you use both generate identical bytecode.

Comment: @DonalFellows: yep, it's mostly a stylistic issue. Not that style is immaterial.

Comment: Yep. I mostly use the `return $x` version since then it's clear that that's exactly what I intend.

Comment: Thank you peter, to point me my misunderstanding with the braces ,furthermore this procedure was not a member of my class.. thanks , It's not a good idea to change the format of values , it's better as you make , I don't understand the "constructor",  now yes !

Comment: Can you explain me , why 'constructor args' allows me to take all elements and not the first ?

Comment: It's `args` that is special. If the last parameter name is `args`, then after any preceding parameters have been given argument values, the remaining argument values are packed up in a list and assigned to `args`. This makes it possible to define commands that take a variable number of arguments. If `args` is the only parameter name, all of the argument values are assigned to it.